# Normal families of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

If a set $F=\{f: f$ is holomorphic on $G, G $ is open in $C \}$ is normal. we want to show that $F'=\{f': f\in F\}$ the set of the derivatives of function that contained in F is normal. And what about the converse.
I know that the converse is not true but can we but some conditions to be true or not?

Comment: Does your definition of normality include or exclude sequences converging locally uniformly to $\infty$?

Comment: I think the definition of normality is given by montel's theorem , the family $F $ is normal $iff$ $F$ is locally bounded. And it's corollaries.

Comment: I guess that means the constant $\infty$ is excluded as a limit. Then the converse doesn't hold.

Comment: I think that too, but is there any conditions to become true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do exclude $\infty$ as a limit, if $F$ is normal, then it is locally uniformly bounded.

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $G$ and choose a (piecewise smooth) curve $\gamma$, surrounding $K$ in such a way that 1) $\operatorname{dist}(\gamma, K) = c > 0$ and that 2) $\gamma$ itself is compact in $G$.

Then, using Cauchy's integral theorem and the standard estimation lemma, if $z \in K$ then:
$$
f'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2}\,d\zeta
$$
so
$$
|f'(z)| \le  \frac{1}{2\pi} \ell(\gamma) \max_{\zeta \in K} \left| \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2} \right| \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \ell(\gamma) \frac{M(\gamma)}{c^2}
$$
independently of $f \in F$ and $z \in K$. I.e., $F'$ is uniformly bounded on every compact set $K$, so $F'$ is normal.

Comment: thank you doctor, I still need counter example provide a family not normal and the family of its derivative is normal

Comment: A common counterexample is the family $\mathcal{F}=\{n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$