# problem about derivatives of functions from normal family

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let D be a domain.
Let {fn} be a set of functions that are holomorphic on D and is normal. I’m trying to prove that
{fn’} is also a normal family.

The following is my attempt:

Note that if {Gn} is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of D, then so is {Gn’}.

Now, given any subset of {fn’}.

These indices correspond to a subsequence {fn,k} in {fn}.
Since this family is normal, there exists a subsequence that is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of D, which is denoted by {Fn,k}.

Hence this {Fn,k} again corresponds to a subsequence of the original sequence {fn’｝and this subsequence is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of D, showing that {fn’} is normal.

But I am not sure whether this attempt works.
Can someone tell me if my attempt is correct?

And I think this can be proved by using Cauchy Integral formula and some estimation.

Could someone use this idea to prove?

[I think the answer here would be helpful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287645/normal-families-of-holomorphic-functions)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287645/normal-families-of-holomorphic-functions

Comment: The subsequence argument works.